# List of Oracle Table Names created by me only, leaving out the auto-generated table names

Tags: sql, oracle

I realized that we can use `select table_name from user_tables;` to get the list of table names accessible by the current user. I have used this command and I was getting a lot many table names that were created by the system (oracle system) along with the tables that I have created. I used Oracle10XE, and got about 140 table names.

Actually I have created only 2 tables. Is there any way to differentiate between my own 2 tables from other auto-generated tables?

I have logged in using the "system" user that comes by default. I have not created any new users.

Actually I wanted to take the list of my table names and show them in a List control in my Java program.

Comment: You should ***NOT*** use the `SYSTEM` account for anything else the configuring Oracle. Create a new regular user and create your tables there. The tables that you see are oracle internal system tables and belong to the `SYSTEM` user. And those _are_ the tables "you" created because you "are" `SYSTEM` when you log in as `SYSTEM` (did I mention you should never use the `SYSTEM` or `SYS` count for "normal work"?)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.<br>Yes, i understood that i was getting table names under SYSTEM user. I want to know whether there is any way to differentiate between those Internal-Tables and MyOwnTables. Please let me know.

Comment: Those *are* your "own" tables because you *are* SYSTEM. The solutioni is simple: do **not** use the `system` account, use a regular user account and you don't have that problem

Comment: The only way to distinguish the tables you've added from the existing SYSTEM schema objects would be to use the DATE_CREATED from the USER_OBJECTS view.  However, you should not do this.  Instead as everybody else suggests you should create a new account for your application schema.  Adding objects to SYSTEM might break the database and would invalidate any support contract.  Clearly you don't care about this but you ought to.

Comment: @a_horse and APC: Thank you for valuable suggestions from both of you. I will always create a new account and forget using SYSTEM user for normal/application activities.